# Safe authentication with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Am failry new to authentication logic, would anyone be able to tell me if I am missing something here as it seems a little too good to be true. I validate users using something like this;

```
        if (validateUser(form.Email, form.Password))
        {
            return signIn(form.Email);
        }
```

the validateUser function returns a boolean value. Sign in then does something like this;

```
    public void signIn(string email)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(nameOfUser, false);
    }
```

Which will subsequently allow me to do things like this for all future requests;

```
string userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
Profile p = Profile.getProfileFor(userEmail);
```

This seems a little too simple to be safe! Is there anything I'm missing here / any blindingly obvious security risks? Or is this basically how it's done?

Regards,

Mike

Comment: What makes you think that it is not safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much more you can do with security:

- Encrypt the password
- Log every login attempt with IP address to identify attacks
- Use an integer identity column instead of email:

  This will make the app leaner and faster.

  If you use a number instead of email a hacker would have a harder time associating the information(user) to hack. You can learn so much from a user just by having his email

.

- Cache the identity
- Use roles

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should use HTTPS to avoid man in the middle attacks but this is not something done in code. Also it is not obvious from your code if you are hashing the passwords as you should be.

BTW the .NET convention is to use PascalCase for method names.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it is done, correct.

The only security risk to note is the same as with all form posts, in that all values entered by the end-user into the browser are sent back to the server in plain text, including the password.  So, this exposes the possibility of someone trying to sniff the traffic for passwords, for which you can use https to get around that problem.